# C# WebBrowser control eventually stops rendering css animation

Tags: c#, css, animation, browser, dashboard

I have created a C# Windows Forms application, which queries TeamCity and Service information from our Test Environments etc.
It then parses the information and spits the data out in the form of an html page.
I then render the page in a WebBrowser control.

I use the following CSS to set anything with an error to be a flashing red background color.

```
@-webkit-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@-moz-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@-o-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
.invalid {
  -webkit-animation: invalid 1s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    invalid 1s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      invalid 1s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         invalid 1s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

This works, the dashboard looks really good, however after leaving the C# Application running for maybe an hour or so, the flashing stops and the only way to fix it is to stop the application, and restart.

The weird thing is that the Application is using a

while(true) true loop, in order to refresh the page every 2 minutes. 
So technically, the page is refreshed every 2 minutes, but the styles never come back.

Because I am setting the html content from a background thread, I am using the following to change the html content without thread access exceptions.

```
 delegate void WriteHtmlDelegate(string sText);
        public void WriteHtml(string sText)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                // We're not in the UI thread, so we need to call BeginInvoke
                BeginInvoke(new WriteHtmlDelegate(WriteHtml), new object[] { sText });
                return;
            }
            wbStatus.DocumentText = "0";
            wbStatus.Document.OpenNew(true);
            wbStatus.Document.Write(sText);
            wbStatus.Refresh();
        }
```

When the issue occurs, and the style stops flashing, I am able to right click and view source. I am able to see that my style is still intact, and the table tds that I am setting the class of are also properly set.
So it appears to be a render problem.

I don't think changing the capabilities of the application via registry hacks will work, since that doesn't explain why it works for 1 hour, then stops.

Is there an upper limit to css animations? Is infinite actually just a really long time?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but if you are working on a  "custom" browser, surely it has a specific rendering engine. If you are running the browser on a Trident engine for example, you would not need to prefix and just use the IE animation.

Comment: It is not a custom browser, it is a WebBrowser control from the .Net 4.5.
If I'm not mistaken, it is basically an Internet Explorer window within a Windows Form. Im pretty sure that what you just said would have a binary outcome. It either works, or it doesn't work. My scenario is that it works for an hour or two, then stops rendering css animations. (its like the animations just stop despite them being marked as infinite duration)